# Will hadoop replace data warehousing?

Tags: hadoop, data-warehouse

I've heard reports that Hadoop is poised to replace data warehousing.  So I was wondering if there were actual case studies done with success/failure rates or if some of the developers here had worked on a project where this was done, either totally or partially?

With the advent of "Big Data" there seems to be a lot of hype with it and I'm trying to figure out fact from fiction.

We have a huge database conversion in the works and I'm thinking this may be an alternative solution.

Comment: I'd say yes, we are currently migrating data out of Teradata as quickly as possible, we will save a ton of money and be able start doing some cool Machine Learning stuff with Spark.  But I'll also say your going to get a ton of pedants want to close your question because it's too interesting.

Comment: I felt that asking the question was worth it, even it I get down voted or it's closed out.  Please put your comments into an a more descriptive and fuller explanation of what you are doing and how in your answer.  I don't know of anyone else personally that has tried to do this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok so there are a lot of success stories out there with Big Data startups, especially in AdTech, though it's not so much "replace" the old expensive proprietary ways but they are just using Hadoop first time round.  This I guess is the benefit of being a startup - no legacy systems.  Advertising, although somewhat boring from the outside, is very interesting from a technical and data science point of view.  There is a huge amount of data and the challenge is to more efficiently segment users and bid for ad space.  This usually means some machine learning is involved.

It's not just AdTech though, Hadoop is used in banks for fraud detection and various other transactional analysis.

So my two cents as to why this is happening I'll try to summarise with a comparison of my main experience, that is using HDFS with Spark and Scala, vs traditional approaches that use SAS, R & Teradata:

1. HDFS is a very very very effective way to store huge amounts of data in an easily accessible distributed way without the overhead of first structuring the data.
2. HDFS does not require custom hardware, it works on commodity hardware and is therefore cheaper per TB.
3. HDFS & the hadoop ecosystem go hand in glove with dynamic and flexible cloud architectures.  Google Cloud and Amazon AWS have such rich and cheap features that completely eliminate the need for in house DCs.  There is no need to buy 20 powerful servers and 100s TB of storage to then discover it's not enough, or it's too much, or it's only needed for 1 hour a day. Setting up a cluster with cloud services is getting easier and easier, there are even scripts out there that make doing it possible for those with only a small amount of sysadm/devops experience.
4. Hadoop and Spark, particularly when used with a high level statically typed language like Scala (but Java 8 is also OK-ish) means data scientists can now do things they could never do with scripting languages like R, Python and SAS.  First they can wire up their modelling code with other production systems, all in one language, all in one virtual environment.  Think about all the high velocity tools written in Scala; Kafka, Akka, Spray, Spark, SparkStreaming, GraphX etc, and in Java: HDFS, HBase, Cassandra - now all these tools are highly interoperable.  What this means is for first time in history, data analysts can reliably automate analytics and build stable products.  They have the high-level functionality they need, but with the predictability and reliability of static typing, FP and unit testing.  Try building a large complicated concurrent system in Python. Try writting unit tests in R or SAS.  Try compiling your code, watching the tests pass, and conclude "hey it works! lets ship it" in a dynamically typed language.

These four points combined means that A: storing data is now a lot lot cheaper, B: processing data is now a lot lot cheaper and C: human resource costs are much much cheaper as now you don't need several teams siloed off into analysts, modellers, engineers, developers, you can mash these skills together to make hybrids ultimately needing to employ less people.

Things won't change over night, currently the labour market is majorly lacking two groups; good Big Data DevOps and Scala engineers/developers, and their rates clearly reflect that.  Unfortunately the supply is quite low even though the demand is very high. Although I still conjecture Hadoop for warehousing is much cheaper, finding talent can be a big costs that is restricting the pace of transition.